# Are the Therin gods real?

Tags: gentlemen-bastards, scott-lynch

In Scott Lynch's *Gentleman Bastard* series, are the Twelve/Thirteen (listed below) supposed to be real? By this I mean if within that universe, they are supposed to be real entities, or merely the deities of a made up religion?

- Iono - The Lord of the Grasping Water, god of the sea.
- Aza Guilla - The Lady of the Long Silence, goddess of death.
- Perelandro - Lord of the Overlooked, god of mercy and charity.
- Gandolo - Lord of Coin and Commerce, god of merchants and trade.
- Nara - The Lady of Ubiquitous Maladies, goddess of sickness and poison.
- Morgante - The Lord of Noose and Trowel, god of law and order.
- Callo Androno - The Eyes on the Crossroad, god of travel, languages and lore.
- Preva - Lady of the Red Madness, goddess of love, madness and inspiration.
- Venaportha - The Lady With Two Faces, goddess of luck.
- Dama Elliza - Mother of Rains and Reaping, goddess of agriculture and farming.
- Sendovani - goddess of secrets, mysteries, knowledge, alchemy.
- Azri - god of nature, weather and war.
- The Nameless Thirteenth - The Crooked Warden, the Benefactor, god of thieves.

Comment: I don't think they appear as characters, but they seem to be as real to their adherents as any deity, fictional or otherwise